# MySQL Query - order ID by JSON values

Tags: mysql, json, sorting

I have table that holds sort json number values that i need to sort id using defined json sort number...so i have table like this:

```
+----+------------+-----------------+
| id | channel    | sort            |
+----+------------+-----------------+
|  1 | US_CH 1    | ["1", "2", "4"] |
|  4 | US_CH 4    | ["1", "2", "4"] |
|  2 | US_CH 2    | ["1", "2", "4"] |
+----+------------+-----------------+
```

And would like to get to get this:

```
+----+------------+-----------------+
| id | channel    | sort            |
+----+------------+-----------------+
|  1 | US_CH 1    | ["1", "2", "4"] |
|  2 | US_CH 2    | ["1", "2", "4"] |
|  4 | US_CH 4    | ["1", "2", "4"] |
+----+------------+-----------------+
```

So the point is to get ID sort by value of json sort values in array. I know that sort json values are not json structure but i need to get using this number because i im working channel editor that update and add channels that have 5000 records (enigma2 stb) so i need using this number because it will store small data in database and inserting and updating will be more faster.

I try using JSON_SEARCH to extract single value but i need all values so that i can use like ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT(sort, '$[extract numbers]')

Comment: What if different rows have different `sort` values?

Comment: looking your example you can order by id also

Comment: @knowledge.... It's presumably just an example, the `sort` arrays could be in a different order.

Comment: I have one more row after sort that is called bouquet..so bouquet id 1 will have different channels and different id but will have sort field same for all bouquets that have numer id 1

Comment: @John please give us a better example with different values on the `sort` cell of your rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY LOCATE(sort, CONCAT('"', id, '"'))
```

Comment: Nice query but it does not sort using sort json numbers...i get result like first example in question..thanks for trying

Comment: What does "sort using sort json numbers" mean? I thought you wanted to sort the IDs in the same order that they appear in the JSON array. `LOCATE` returns the character position in the string, so if it's further in the array, it will also be further in the string. I don't think there's any way to return an array index in MySQL, so this is the closest you can get.

Comment: Yes it returns id but i think that in sort json returns string not numbers...and i will not try to convert it to integer and try to sort...i need to try but i think your sql is what i need...i will click accepted as soon i get sorting rigth...thanks for helping me out

Comment: I converted string to number using your query and this works as expected..thank you.

Comment: `LOCATE()` doesn't return a string, it returns a number. There's nothing to convert.

Comment: I know...but it did not work...when i convert it to integer it works..strange but most important is that above code works and very fast....

Comment: So you use `CONVERT(LOCATE(sort, CONCAT('"', id, '"')), DECIMAL)`?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you would need to use that `CONVERT` call. `LOCATE` already returns a number, there's no need to convert it.